# Why do I get a 12031 error message after doing a Get

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

I try to call a page every 5 minutes to keep my session active. Because, there is a treatment in progress which can last 45 minutes. And once the treatment is finished, we call the StopCall method.
Unfortunately after the second call I get an error saying "12031 unkown". Please help resolve. thank you in advance.

```
      var counter;
      var g_verifiertermine; 
      var minute = 60 * 1000;
      var refreshTime = 5 * minute;
      counter = 0;


    function checkTraitement() {
        g_verifiertermine = setInterval("VerifierTermine()", refreshTime);
    }

    function VerifierTermine() {
        $.get(
            "../SessionCheck.aspx?counter=" +counter
        ).error(function (hr, statusText)
        {
            if (hr.statusText == 'Unknown') {
                console.log("Code error : " + hr.status + " Text : " + hr.statusText + " counter : " 
                             + counter);
                return;
            }                
        });
    }

    function StopCall() { 
        clearInterval(g_verifiertermine);  
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I need to refresh my memory but I believe for promises you should be doing it differently. shouldn't it be `$.get().then((succes) =>{}, (error)  =>{})` not `.error`?

secondly, put a break point on your server call and make the timeout shorter for your tests. Or simply take a look at your network tab in your browser and inspect the network call it might help.

Comment: Looking at the network tab of my browser, after two minutes of waiting, I observe an Abundant response. I believe that we must increase the waiting time for an IIS response ...

Comment: `Because, there is a treatment in progress which can last 45 minutes` what does this mean exactly? Generally if you have a long running process your client (browser) should simply send the request and a job should start on your server. The job can have a status which can be polled by the client or use socket.io / singalR to update clients realtime. There really shouldn't too many reasons why your http request should be open for 45 minutes. If I understand your current workflow